# How to disable Wordpress Media resize different size version?

Tags: uploads, media, media-library

When I upload to a media, WordPress is resize it to many versions like that

2016-04-03_23-36-35-90x65.png
2016-04-03_23-36-35-120x80.png
2016-04-03_23-36-35-360x240.png
2016-04-03_23-36-35-480x320.png
2016-04-03_23-36-35-600x400.png
2016-04-03_23-36-35-768x391.png
2016-04-03_23-36-35-840x420.png
2016-04-03_23-36-35-840x543.png
2016-04-03_23-36-35-1067x480.png

How can I disable it? I just want to just the original size. So my WordPress version is 4.5.3.

Comment: Settings-->Media and setting each box for width and height to 0 This is not worked for wp 4.5.3

Answer (score 6):

WordPress has some standard images `thumbnail`,`medium`,`medium_large`,`large` for which image sizes you can set it under `Settings --> Media` except `medium_large` size whose default height set to `768px` ( medium_large is available from WP4.4).

So when you set **0** to in the media settings it won't generate a thumbnail, medium size, or large size images and it didn't as far as I can see from your generated sizes. So the generated images are added by the active theme or plugins you have.

Anyway, we can remove those image sizes using the following code.

```
function wpse_230632_remove_image_sizes() {
    foreach ( get_intermediate_image_sizes() as $size ) {
        remove_image_size( $size );
    }
}
add_action('init', 'wpse_230632_remove_image_sizes');
```

One thing remained and that is `medium_large` size, for this:

We need to set `medium_large_size_w` and `medium_large_size_h` to **0** .
You can set this in DB directly or update the option once like this:

```
update_option('medium_large_size_w',0);
update_option('medium_large_size_h',0);
```

Now try to upload sample images and check image sizes, you will only see the original image.

Comment: The medium_large trick is amazing, i don't know why wp devs don't bother to add it to the interface! but waste time on emojis...

Comment: For some reason, I see like 150 on 150, 300 on 300 and 1024 on 1024 still generating...

Comment: It might also happen when the theme or plugin has registered custom images.